# Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-proxy_1.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Tags: system-installation

This is the response i get when I am upgrading ubuntu 14.04 lts to 16.04 lts. Entire 3554 packages are fetched, which is the 3rd step during upgrading, afer the packages are fetched the error message displaying
 Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/iio-sensor-proxy/iio-sensor-proxy_1.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried deleting the offending package from the apt cache?